# Why does append() modify the provided slice? (See example)

Tags: go

You can [run the example code](http://play.golang.org/p/0QJR5oOzYm) on Go Playground.

Here is the code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    numbers := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

    fmt.Println(numbers)
    _ = append(numbers[0:1], numbers[2:]...)
    fmt.Println(numbers)
}
```

Output:

```
[1 2 3 4 5]
[1 3 4 5 5]
```

Why was the `numbers` slice modified by append? Is this expected behavior and if yes, could you explain to me why? I thought `append` doesn't modify its arguments.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

See http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals.

The append function *could* allocate a new underlying array if what you are appending to the slice does not fit in the current slice's capacity. Append *does* modify the underlying array. The reason you have to assign back to the variable is because, as I said in the first sentence, the underlying array could be reallocated and the old slice will still point to the old array.

See [this play example](http://play.golang.org/p/yaNoCIu-gV) to see exactly what I am talking about.

Comment: thanks for the play example, makes it clearer