# How to remove an item from a slice repeatedly?

Tags: go, slice

I would like to create multiple slices from one array. One slice each with one element missing. I am using this code ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/cKfPq-jFHmI)):

```
nums := []int{1,2,3}
for i := 0; i < len(nums); i++ {
    fmt.Println(append(nums[:i], nums[i+1:]...))
}
```

I was expecting to receive

```
[2 3]
[1 3]
[1 2]
```

But instead I receive

```
[2 3]
[2 3]
[2 3]
```

Why is that?

Comment: So, I guess I am always appending to `nums`. But how do I prevent that?

Comment: `append(nums[:i], nums[i+1:]...)` modifies the values *inside* the slice's underlying array if they can fit, so the first iteration changes the `nums` underlying array to be `[2 3 3]`, and so on.

Comment: I guess this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35920534/why-does-append-modify-passed-slice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As mkopriva correctly pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68336955/how-to-remove-an-item-from-a-list-repeatedly#comment120774649_68336955), the output of your program differs from what you expect because all slices resulting from `append` share the same underlying array. You need to somehow decouple those slices from the underlying array of slice `nums`.

One viable approach is indeed to use `copy`, as you did in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68337092/2541573). There is a more concise alternative, although it may not be clearer to untrained eyes.

Rather than resorting to `copy`, you can use `nums[:i:i]` (a [*full-slice expression*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions), a.k.a. *three-index slice*) as the first argument of `append`:

```golang
nums := []int{1,2,3}
for i := 0; i < len(nums); i++ {
  fmt.Println(append(nums[:i:i], nums[i+1:]...))
}
```

The resulting slice will be decoupled from slice `nums`'s underlying array and you'll get the desired output:

```
[2 3]
[1 3]
[1 2]
```

([Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/uULKbheUmB0))

Since Go 1.18, you can use functions `Clone` and `Delete` from the [`golang.org/x/exp/slices` package](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/slices) to achieve the same result in an arguably more readable fashion:

```
func main() {
  nums := []int{1, 2, 3}
  for i := 0; i < len(nums); i++ {
    fmt.Println(slices.Delete(slices.Clone(nums), i, i+1))
  }
}
```

([Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/6D_R5b6bjta))

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for pointing this out to me. This is my current solution. It simply copies the array on which I am working ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/HBFmzSzw1UQ))

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    nums := []int{1,2,3}
        for i := 0; i < len(nums); i++ {
            cpy := make([]int, len(nums))
            copy(cpy, nums)
            fmt.Println(append(cpy[:i], cpy[i+1:]...))
        }
}
```