# My Go recursive function not working as expected due to slices

Tags: go, slice

I have written a function and I can't seem to find where the bug is:

The function `change` works like this:

An input of 15 (target value) with possible values of [1, 5, 10, 25, 100] should return [5, 10]. That's because to reach a target value of 15, the least amount of numbers to make up that target number is to have a 10 and 5

I use a caching mechanism, as it is a recursive function and remembers the values that have already been calculated.

```
func Change(coins []int, target int, resultsCache map[int][]int) ([]int, error) {
    if val, ok := resultsCache[target]; ok {
        return val, nil
    }
    if target == 0 {
        return make([]int, 0), nil
    }
    if target < 0 {
        return nil, errors.New("Target can't be less than zero")
    }

    var leastNumOfCoinChangeCombinations []int
    for _, coin := range coins {
        remainder := target - coin
        remainderCombination, _ := Change(coins, remainder, resultsCache)

        if remainderCombination != nil {
            combination := append(remainderCombination, coin)
            if leastNumOfCoinChangeCombinations == nil || len(combination) < len(leastNumOfCoinChangeCombinations) {
                leastNumOfCoinChangeCombinations = combination
            }
        }
    }
    if leastNumOfCoinChangeCombinations == nil {
        return nil, errors.New("Can't find changes from coin combinations")
    }
    sort.Ints(leastNumOfCoinChangeCombinations)
    resultsCache[target] = leastNumOfCoinChangeCombinations
    return leastNumOfCoinChangeCombinations, nil
}
```

The cache however have some abnormal behaviour, for example if I want to use the value of 12 in the cache later, instead of getting [2,5,5], I get [1 2 5] instead. Not sure where I went wrong. (but initially it was calculated and stored correctly, not sure how it got changed).

Here is a playground I used for troubleshooting:

https://play.golang.org/p/Rt8Sh_Ul-ge

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are encountering a fairly common, but sometimes difficult to spot, issue caused by the way slices work. Before reading further it's probably worth scanning the blog post [Go Slices: usage and internals](https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro). The issue stems from the way `append` can reuse the slices underlying array as per this quote from the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices):

> If the capacity of s is not large enough to fit the additional values, append allocates a new, sufficiently large underlying array that fits both the existing slice elements and the additional values. Otherwise, **append re-uses the underlying array**.

The below code provides a simple demonstration of what is occurring:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
    x := []int{2, 3}
    x2 := append(x, 4)
    x3 := append(x2, 1)
    fmt.Println("x2 before sort", x2)
    sort.Ints(x3)
    fmt.Println("x2 after sort", x2)
    fmt.Println("x3", x3)
    fmt.Println("x2 cap", cap(x2))
}
```

The results are ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/B0BlTU8ZVVh)):

```
x2 before sort [2 3 4]
x2 after sort [1 2 3]
x3 [1 2 3 4]
x2 cap 4
```

The result is probably not what you expected - why did `x2` change when we sorted `x3`? The reason this happens is that the backing array for `x2` has a capacity of 4 (length is 3) and when we `append` 1 the new slice `x3` uses the same backing array (capacity 4, length 4). This only becomes an issue when we make a change to the portion of the backing array used by `x2` and this happens when we call `sort` on `x3`.

So in your code you are adding a slice to the map but it's backing array is then being altered after that instance of `Change` returns (the append/sort ends up happening pretty much as in the example above).

There are a few ways you can fix this; removing the sort will do the trick but is probably not what you want. A better alternative is to take a copy of the slice; you can do this by replacing `combination := append(remainderCombination, coin)` with:

```
combination := make([]int, len(remainderCombination)+1)
copy(combination , remainderCombination)
combination[len(remainderCombination)] = coin
```

or the simpler (but perhaps not as easy to grasp - [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/SJ1YwZK_0BK)):

```
combination := append([]int{coin}, remainderCombination...)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this, I tried to debug for a long time and couldn't figure out why. All my test cases are passing now. This is very useful. Cheers.

Comment: No worries - took me a while to spot the flaw (not sure of the reasons for the downvotes; this is a fairly common problem but can be very difficult to spot and you provided all relevant info). If this solves the issue please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) (makes it easier for others to see that your issue is resolved).

Comment: The second suggested solution is much better in my opinion. The spread operator works just like in the javascript whereby it unfolds the slices into multiple values/arguments.

Comment: The first example is [as per the spec examples](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices), clearer (obvious that a copy is happening) and probably a [bit faster](https://gist.github.com/xogeny/b819af6a0cf8ba1caaef). However I agree that the second option looks nicer!

Comment: @Brits You could use a three-index slice instead of `copy`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68399463/2541573

Comment: @jub0bs I did consider using `append(remainderCombination[:len(remainderCombination): len(remainderCombination)], coin)`, which works OK, but that felt more difficult to understand (for someone new to go) so I omitted it.

Comment: Thanks guys, playing with code snippets is best way to learn. https://play.golang.org/p/aUScdZJ8DEB Subsitiude line 8 with a 3 index slice - `y := x[:2:2]`. And one can see the results easily.