# How to reuse slice with sync.Pool in golang?

Tags: go, slice, pool

Consider this code:

```
type TestStruct struct {
    Name string
}

func TestSliceWithPool(t *testing.T) {
    var slicePool = sync.Pool{
        New: func() interface{} {
            t.Log("i am created")
            s := make([]interface{}, 0)
            return s
        },
    }

    s, _ := slicePool.Get().([]interface{})
    t.Logf("Lenth: %d, Cap: %d, Pointer: %p", len(s), cap(s), s)
    for i := 0; i < 9000; i++ {
        st := &TestStruct{Name: "test"}
        s = append(s, st)
    }
    for _, v := range s {
        if value, ok := v.(TestStruct); ok {
            if value.Name != "test" {
                t.Error("u are changed!")
            }
        }
    }
    s = s[:0]
    slicePool.Put(s)

    s2, _ := slicePool.Get().([]interface{})
    t.Logf("Lenth: %d, Cap: %d, Pointer: %p", len(s), cap(s), s)
    for i := 0; i < 8000; i++ {
        st := &TestStruct{Name: "test2"}
        s2 = append(s2, st)
    }
    for _, v := range s2 {
        if value, ok := v.(TestStruct); ok {
            if value.Name != "test2" {
                t.Error("u are changed!")
            }
        }
    }
    slicePool.Put(s2)
}
```

The result of test is:

```
slice_test.go:63: i am created
slice_test.go:70: Lenth: 0, Cap: 0, Pointer: 0x1019598
slice_test.go:86: Lenth: 0, Cap: 9728, Pointer: 0xc000500000
```

Why is it generated only once but the address is different? And Why the cap is 9728?
Is there any problem when I use the same slice like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is it generated only once but the address is different?

Because in the first for loop you append to it beyond its capacity, which in `New` is set to zero, and reassign to it the result of `append`. For details: [Why does append() modify the provided slice? (See example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395261/why-does-append-modify-the-provided-slice-see-example)

> Is there any problem when I use the same slice like this?

There could be. When you reslice `s` with `s = s[:0]`, you are resetting the length *but not the capacity*. The backing array is still the same one from the previous append-and-reassign operation.

So if you append again to `s2`, the capacity will be enough to not cause reallocation, and you'll end up overwriting the first elements of the backing array:

A demonstrative example:

```
func TestSliceWithPool(t *testing.T) {
    var slicePool = sync.Pool{
        New: func() interface{} {
            t.Log("Created")
            s := make([]interface{}, 0)
            return s
        },
    }

    s, _ := slicePool.Get().([]interface{})
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        s = append(s, i)
    }
    fmt.Println(s) 
    // ^ output: [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

    s = s[:0]
    slicePool.Put(s)

    s2, _ := slicePool.Get().([]interface{})
    fmt.Println(s)
    // ^ output: []

    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        s2 = append(s2, i*10)
    }
    fmt.Println(s2) 
    // ^ output: [0 10 20 30 40]

    fmt.Println(s2[:10])
    // ^ output: [0 10 20 30 40 5 6 7 8 9]
}
```

This might be okay, since you now have a slice with extended capacity that doesn't need reallocation on append, but it could also be a memory leak if your application keeps around other slice headers pointing to the same backing array (as in case of `s` and `s2`), thus preventing garbage collection of the buffers.