# Weird behaviour of append in Go

Tags: go

I'm attempting to solve the Subsets problem on [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/subsets/) using Go. I've come up with the following solution:

```
func subsets(nums []int) [][]int {
    sol := make([][]int,0)
    temp:= make([]int,0)

    var backtrack func(idx int)
    backtrack = func(idx int) {
        sol = append(sol, temp)
        fmt.Println(temp, append([]int{},temp...))

        if idx == len(nums) {
            return
        }

        for i:= idx; i<len(nums);i++{
            temp = append(temp,nums[i])
            backtrack(i+1)
            temp = temp[:len(temp)-1]
        }

    }
    backtrack(0)
    return sol

}
```

However, this solution is incorrect. I have noticed that I need to use append(sol, append([]int{}, temp...)) instead of just sol = append(sol, temp).

Even though the fmt.Println(temp, append([]int{}, temp...)) statement produces the same output for both temp and append([]int{}, temp...), the corrected version using append([]int{}, temp...) actually works. Can someone explain the difference between temp and append([]int{}, temp...) in this context? Why does the corrected version work while the initial version does not?

Expected `temp` and `append([]int{},temp...)` to be the same

Comment: It's slice aliasing.

Comment: It's undefined (decision happens at runtime based on current length and amount of allocated space, and how that compares to the number of items to be added) whether `append` does a mutation purely in-place or returns an updated item. You can't depend on it being one or the other, so you need to _always_ assume it could be both.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does append modify passed slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35920534/why-does-append-modify-passed-slice) -- it's also duplicative of [Why does append modify the provided slice? (See example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395261/why-does-append-modify-the-provided-slice-see-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `sol = append(sol, temp)` is that you're adding the slice `temp` into `sol`, not the items "inside" the slice. A slice, as described on [Slice internals blog article](https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro), is "just" a pointer to an array, a length and a capacity.

Therefore, in your case, since `temp` is **reused** in each iteration, the content of the array under `temp` slice is overridden, and the values inside the slice you've previously added to `sol` are also modified (since the array under the slice is modified). This is why you're getting the wrong result at the end, even if your `fmt.Println` statement shows that before appending, `temp` has the correct value.

As `append([]int{}, temp...)` creates a new slice, there is no chance the values are mutated inside that new slice, since it's not reused.